# fetching a page from facebook with curl/file_get_contents

Tags: php, facebook

I try to get content from my facebook page like so:

echo  file_get_contents("http://www.facebook.com/dma.y");

The problem  is that it doesnt give me the page but redirects me to another page that says that I need to upgrade my browswer. Then I thought to use curl and fetch it by sending a request with some headers.

```
 echo get_follow_url('http://www.facebook.com/dma.y');
function get_follow_url($url){
        // must set $url first. Duh...
    $http = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); 
       curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, get_headers('http://google.com'));
    // do your curl thing here
    $result = curl_exec($http);



 if(curl_errno($http)){ 
     echo "<br/>An error has been thrown!<br/>";
    exit(); 
 }
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($http, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($http);
return $http_status;
}
```

Still there is no luck. I should have a status code response returned which is either 404 or 200.. depending if I am logged into facebook.  But it returns 301, cause it identifies my request as not being a regular browser request. so what am I missing in the curl option settings?

**UPDATE**
What I am actually trying to do is to replicate this functionality:

The script will trigger the function onload or onerror, depending on the status code returned..

That code will retrieve the page. However, that javascript method is clumsy, and breaks in some browsers like firefox..cause it isnt a javascript file.

Comment: Scraping Facebook pages is a bad idea. Make use of the Graph API instead to get the info you want.

Comment: Oh really, and let me guess, I need an app id for everything..no thank you

Comment: You’re welcome. Everything else is just stupid bricolage.

Comment: If you have a better idea, you could state it, Otherwise,,, save typing

Comment: Getting better answers starts with asking better questions. You have not explained what you are actually trying to achieve, or _why_ you think scraping would be a better idea than using the API.

Comment: I am trying to get a response code from the page.. I am not interested in scrapping it.. simply getting a response code

Comment: @dim - Explaining to us what you are trying to achieve would go a long way in helping us to understand the problems. With some background information we might be able to come up with a way to do what you need in a totally different (and easier) way. Context is everything...

Comment: First you talked about getting _content_, and now it’s just a _response code_. And what do you _want to do_ with that code …?

Answer (score 4):

What you might want to try is to set the `user_agent` with CURL.

```
$url = 'https://www.facebook.com/cocacola';
$http = curl_init($url);
$fake_user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7) Gecko/20040803 Firefox/0.9.3';
curl_setopt($http, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $fake_user_agent); 
$result = curl_exec($http);
```

This is the parameter that servers look at to see what browser you are using. I'm not 100% sure if this will bypass Facebook's checks and give you ALL the information on the page, but it's definitely worth a try! :)

Comment: hmm... now it gives me This content is currently unavailable 404.. but it does so even if i am logged in. I think the problem is in the headers too

Comment: It's also an issue of privacy.. The url I tested with is a "public" page. You don't have to be logged in to see it. With user pages I think this might be an issue... You might have to find a way to authenticate with Facebook through your CURL script, and that is a totally different story :P